# View will not group the taxonomy terms

Tags: views, commerce

I am litterally pulling my hair out and I hope that someone can help!  I'm working in Drupal 7 with Commerce Kickstart and all I want is to be able to view the flowers, grouped by their taxonomy term.

For example: 
Flowers with bloom size of 5.5 inches:
flower teaser      flower teaser      flower teaser      flower teaser

Flowers with bloom size of 4 inches
flower teaser      flower teaser      flower teaser      flower teaser

etc.

Right now in the view I'm using the "grid" format grouping by the Taxonomy term name Bloom size - I have the "use rendered output to group rows" checked, but it will not group my terms and it keeps putting the same heading on down the page above each teaser.  You can see it here:  64.34.70.141/~henryl/bloom-size

I have a feeling it's something simple that I'm missing but I've spent DAYS on this one page and combing through other view examples and google searches and I can't figure it out.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!!!!!!

Candace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you have the "sort" criteria set to? Also, I find the default Views grid-view to be quite awful. I use the [Views Fixed Grid](http://drupal.org/project/views_fixed_grid) module for any grid views. It will give you better output and greater control in my humble opinion.

Comment: The other pages I used the unformatted list - which I like better since this is supposed to be a responsive design, BUT, I need the fields to be able to populate the Taxonomy term title and group them together - at least that's the only way I've found so far.  I'm sorting by "Bloom Size (asc).

Comment: I've found part of my problem - Under the Grid settings I had "Use Rendered output to group rows" checked.  When i unchecked it - it then grouped everything under the titles and put them in the rows properly.  Still wondering though if there's a way to do this using an unordered list so that it's more responsive to different screen sizes...??

Comment: Ah I'm a dummy... I must have been really tired!  I was playing around and the unordered list now works. I don't know why but I thought you couldn't use an unordered list with fields...  Woo Hoo!!  Thanks!!